# Understanding XCode debug area error messages

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For example, I get this error in debug area:

```
2014-05-01 05:01:28.052 MyApp[93187:303] *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: -1)
2014-05-01 05:01:28.057 MyApp[93187:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cb3f25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89202e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca3a46e -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 1102
    3   MyApp                               0x0000000100009725 +[SystemTools getData:] + 5509
    4   MyApp                               0x0000000100001c4b -[AppDelegate drawCanvas:] + 1467
    5   MyApp                               0x0000000100001675 -[AppDelegate repeatingTimer:] + 85
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ec480f4 __NSFireTimer + 96
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8caa6564 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8caa609f __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1151
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8cb175aa __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca618e5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1525
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ca610b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff875dca0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff875dc7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff875dc5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff907853de _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff90784a2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff90778b2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff90763913 NSApplicationMain + 940
    19  MyApp                               0x0000000100016aa2 main + 34
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9440b5fd start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Unfortunately, I have saveral "setObject:forKey:" calls in "SystemTools getData:" function.

How can I determine to which call this error is related? What that numbers (after plus) means?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an [Execption breakpoint](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) in your break points. This will halt at the line of code which is causing the app to crash. That way you dont have to debug with `NSLogs`.

> The default behavior of Xcode is to stop where the exception is
>   caught, not where the exception is raised!

To explain those lines in the crash logs:
From [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs):

> 2   XYZLib   0x34648e88   0x83000 + 8740

It is basically four columns:

- The frame number – in this case, 2.
- The name of the binary – in this case, XYZLib.
- The address of the function that was called – in this case, 0x34648e88.
- The fourth column is divided into two sub-columns, a base address and an offset. Here it is 0×83000 + 8740, where the first number points to the file, and the second points to the line of code in that file.

Comment: Crash appears after thousands of function calls without errors. I can't use halt for this reason.

Comment: @SergeyE. adding exception break point doesnt halt on each function call. It halts only when an exception is raised . i.e a when crash is about to happen. Go through that link in the post. Its explained in more detail.

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I found out video - hoe to add exception breakpoints: http://xcode-howto.com/how-to-add-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode-objective-c.html

Answer (score 1):

Use breakpoints in all of your setObject:forKey calls. Use NSLog for print some useful information in log. You are a developer so you need to know debugging also.

Comment: This error appears very rare, may be after thousands of "SystemTools getData:" calls without errors. Is breakpoints may help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the output is useful here:

```
setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: -1)
```

The NSDictionary doesn't like nil values, so look for a place in your getData method that could be assigning a nil value to a key of "-1".

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but i have several calls of setObjectForKey: in my function and cannot determine which call causes an error.